# mobile responsive doesnt work when on page's first load

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

hello my mobile responsive code works but not on first launch and when i click homepage it redirects me to index.html and than code works any idea how fix it?

meta viemport tag is fine i also tried      `<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'"> <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></noscript>` this and   `html , body{ min-width: 100vw; max-width: 100vw; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; flex-wrap: nowrap; }`

Comment: First, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to more completely describe your actual result and your desired result, and include enough code so that we can reproduce the problem you are seeing.